# Solving $x - a \log(x)=b$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, closed-form, lambert-w

Let $a>0$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$: Assume there exists an $x >0 $ s.t.
$$x - a\log(x) = b$$
holds. How can it be determined in closed-form?

Comment: By "is it possible" do you mean is the function $x-a\log(x)$ invertible and is $b$ in the domain of the inverse? or do you mean is there a nice way to find it (without resorting to numerical methods of approximation)?

Comment: Note that for some choices (of $a$ and $b$), the answer is no.  For example if $a=1$ and $b=0$.  Then it is equivalent to solving $x=\log(x)$ which has no solutions--at least among the real numbers.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I clarified the question.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that there should be a "nice" closed form?  My suspicion is that (for most choices of $a$ and $b$) there is probably no nice closed form.  To solve, you'll almost certainly need to use a numerical approximation method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** You may express $x$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ using a special function.

From 
$$
x - a\log(x) = b
$$ you deduce, by exponentiation, that
$$
e^x e^{- a\log(x)} = e^b
$$ or, for $a \neq 0$,
$$
-\frac{x}a e^{\large-\frac{x}a}  = -\frac{1}ae^{\large-\frac{b}a}
$$ setting $X=-\dfrac{x}a$, you have to solve
$$
Xe^X=-\frac{1}ae^{\large-\frac{b}a}
$$ giving

> $$
> x=-aW\left(-\frac{1}ae^{\large-\frac{b}a}\right)
> $$

where $W(\cdot)$ is the [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).