# Solving the equation $x=a(1+\ln(x))$, where $a$ is a natural number larger than 1.

Tags: calculus

I can see from a graphing calculator that the above has two solutions. I am trying to find an expression for the larger one in terms of $a$. I am wondering if there is anything better than approximating $\ln(x)$ with its Taylor series and solving like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Solving $x - a \log(x)=b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365118/solving-x-a-logx-b?)

Comment: I believe it is the same form, so this might be considered a duplicate.

Comment: The question linked by @ТymaGaidash resolved my question.